# Copy/paste photos in drawable folder is not working

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to copy/paste photos in drawable folder in android studio. But it isn't working. I have restarting android studio as well as the system. I also have tried to clean the project. Still not working. Dragging images to the folder is also not working. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try to resolve the issue:

1. Make sure that the image file you are trying to copy is in a supported format (such as PNG, JPG, or JPEG) and that the file name
   does not contain any invalid characters or spaces.
2. Check if the drawable folder you are trying to paste the image to is the correct one. Make sure it is located under the "res"
   directory of your Android project.
3. Try copying the image to a different folder (such as the "assets" folder) and see if it works. If it does, you can then try copying it
   back to the drawable folder.
4. Check if there are any permission issues with the drawable folder. Make sure that you have read and write access to the folder and its
   contents.
5. If none of the above steps work, try creating a new drawable folder
   and copy the image to that folder. Then, update the references to
   the image in your project to point to the new location.